# ModuleNotFoundError in spyder but not in jupyter notebook

Tags: python

I am using anaconda and I installed pandas_datareader using
conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader

In jupyter notebook, I can

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
```

However, in spyder, I got below error. why? can anyone help? Thanks

```
    import pandas_datareader.data as web

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'
```

Comment: Your spyder instance is probably running in a different environment.  In both Jupyter and Spyder, run: `import sys`, then `print(sys.executable)`

Comment: Thanks James, yes it turns out spyder is using base enviroment python. how do i correct it for spyder? Thanks

Comment: ok, I solved this issue by installing spyder in this new enviroment. I think for new enviroment, there is no spyder installed.